# Qt/KDE camera app alternative to Cheese in Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, qt, camera, plasma-5

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cheese-common gnome-desktop3-data gnome-video-effects gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common
  libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-common libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libgnome-desktop-3-17
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libyelp0 yelp yelp-xsl
```

Cheese comes with an acceptable amount of " gnomish" dependencies but before installing it I am looking for a more Qt-pure alternative.

Kamera comes by default but it doesn't even see the laptop camera, asks me to select one in a full alphabetical list, Komoso is absent, Kamerka is very basic (no video). I know how to use VLC for this but what other options are there?

***By "alternative to Cheese" I basically mean one that would quickly allow image and video capture.***

Comment: What about "kamera" (not kamerka)?

Comment: @pomsky - mentioned it: no video capture it seems, therefore no alternative. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @pomsky - They are not the same. Kamera comes by default but once started it doesn't even detect the laptop's integrated camera, asks me to select it in a long list. Kamerka can be installed but it cannot capture video, only pictures.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just remember the names from the time I used KDE :-)

Comment: @pomsky - Plasma 5 is a treat, I took a dive with gnome and budgie but now I'm breathing again, no matter the relatively limited offer of apps (very relative: vlc, smplayer are qt). Dolphin makes all other file managers seem a joke

Comment: `kamoso/bionic 3.2.4-1 amd64` tool to take pictures and videos from your webcam. I haven't used it myself.

Comment: @DKBose - I had been looking for that under a wrong (misspelled) name. Please post as an answer too in order for me to mark it as definitive.

Comment: can anyone tell me which device to select in Kamera for Microsoft Lifecam built into surface pro laptop?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the description in `apt show kamoso`, it's a "tool to take pictures and videos from your webcam".

If you want to read about it before installing, the `man` page for 18.04 is here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/kamoso.1.html.

There's also https://userbase.kde.org/Kamoso and https://github.com/KDE/kamoso/

```
sudo apt install kamoso
```

Comment: You should probably link to the project page, not their repository's GitHub mirror: https://userbase.kde.org/Kamoso

Comment: For some reason Kamoso is unable to see my 2nd webcam, but Cheese can.