# Kamoso webcam takes mirrored/inverted image

Tags: kde, webcam, image-processing, kamoso

Trying to quickly get a picture of a CD cover with my laptop in Kubuntu 18.04, I realize Kamoso is showing and taking not the actual image, but an inverted one, a mirror picture.

[image: laterally inverted photo]

This odd behavior cannot be changed in the Kamoso settings, it seems. How can I get normal pictures without the need to edit them in Gwenview with the "Mirror" option?

Comment: Please create tag info for the tag you have created: https://askubuntu.com/edit-tag-wiki/8655

Comment: Could you try `kamerka` instead? That gets things right at least in Kubuntu 18.04. Caution: it doesn't come with a .desktop file and krunner doesn't launch it. You can launch it via the KDE menu.

Comment: Of course, as you've [noted previously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035295/qt-kde-camera-app-alternative-to-cheese-in-kubuntu-18-04), `kamerka` doesn't do video.

Comment: fwiw, kamerka also reverses the image (left/right) & there's no way to change it (kubuntu 18.04, kamerka 0.8.1-1build1) -- just adding since google led to this question & I'm still looking for a fix; perhaps it's a configurable issue external to the apps?)